# Is there any real benefit to using the MicrosoftAjax library?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-ajax

I have been using jQuery for the past couple of years now, and I'm comfortable with it. In every MVC project that I start, the first thing I do is delete the MicrosoftAjax files from the solution. I'm wondering now if there's any value in them though? What can I do with them that I can't easily do with jQuery? Also, why do Microsoft include them with the solution if they're claiming to so whole-heartedly support jQuery?

Comment: Take a look at these two links :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609683/microsoft-ajax-client-library-vs-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498680/pros-and-cons-of-ms-ajax-vs-jquery-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, No and No. They are including it because its their library, but IMHO they will drop the support in future versions.

Comment: I agree Darin! .. the use of the MS library was a hangover from the web-form Ajax days ... It will disappear ... the small MS "web-team" seem to _want_ and _do_ everything in their capabililty to provide the best choices for future developers ... I just hope that their successful efforts so far have not gone un-noticed.